# Sharepoint Mobile Site Form View

Tags: mobile, view, calendar, sharepoint-2013

Im using a calendar on my Sharepoint 2013 site. 
On the main desktop site, the view is of the days/weeks. The normal calendar view.
The problem is this view is not supported on the contemporary mobile site and defaults to the bare html, which is terrible.
My question is, can I change the default view by device?
The calendar view on desktop site and the 'All Events' view on the mobile site.